# AWK apply to all the rows except first few

Tags: unix, awk

I have a report `xyz.rpt` in the below format

```
   # ajsh askj sdjh 54 12
   # jhgj 765 2839
     kjsd sdh sdsdf sdffsdf sdff 
     5464 765 67     65      76
     2356 423 34     45      34
```

and so on

I want to print first 2 header line also along with the output of awk command.

```
awk '{if ( $5 < 65  ) print}' > aaa.rpt
```

Comment: Is that `xyz.rpt` sample the data we are starting with or the format you want when this is complete? Either way can you share BOTh what you are starting with and what you are wanting as a result?

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts, please do edit your question to make your question clear as of now its not clear, like what is the logic of getting expected output.

Comment: @Leo: Your edit did not make your question more clear...   Can you add some reactions on the the answers given, and comment why they are correct, of why they fail ? Or, if all fail, [edit] your question!

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR<=2                          # print 1st 2 lines
FNR>2 && $5+0==$5 && $5<65      # print lines where $5 is numeric and $5 < 65
' xyz.rpt
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
awk 'FNR<=2; FNR>2 && $5+0==$5 && $5 < 65' xyz.rpt
```

This generates:

```
ajsh askj sdjh 54 12
jhgj 765 2839
 2356 423 34     45      34
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { for(i=0;i<2;i++) {getline; print;}}$5<65{print}' input
```

- The `BEGIN` block is executed at the start. `getline` reads a line, which gets outputed.
- `$5<65`  In stead of the `if` construction it's better to use a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as i hoped

```
nawk '($5==+$(5*(+$5<=4^3)))+(3>FNR)'

ajsh askj sdjh 54 12
jhgj 765 2839
 2356 423 34     45      34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR<=2 || ($5+0==$5 && $5<65)' file
```